# Returning multiple values from a clojure macro

Tags: macros, clojure

I need to add several methods to a Clojure `defprotocol` that I am writing for several identical Swing components:

```
(defprotocol view-methods
  (ok-button-add-action-listener     [this listener])
  (ok-button-set-enabled             [this enabled])
  (ok-button-set-selected            [this selected])
  (cancel-button-add-action-listener [this listener])
  (cancel-button-set-enabled         [this enabled])
  (cancel-button-set-selected        [this selected])
  (other-button-add-action-listener  [this listener])
  (other-button-set-enabled          [this enabled])
  (other-button-set-selected         [this selected]))
```

Is there any way that I can write a macro that returns all three of the method signatures (`xxx-button-add-action-listener`, `xxx-button-set-enabled`, `xxx-button-set-selected`)?

```
(defprotocol view-methods
  (add-methods ok)
  (add-methods cancel)
  (add-methods other))
```

This macro needs to add three items to the growing `defprotocol` with each invocation.

Can a macro return `` `~@a-list `` and expand "in place"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you just need to have your macro expand in a `(do ...)`, and the Clojure compiler will thread the `do` children as a sequence of top level forms.

Comment: I'm discovering that from looking at Stuart Sierra's `do-template` macro (http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.template-api.html). I'm experimenting with it as we speak :-). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a macro must expand to a single form - so you can't do this in the exact way you are describing.

However, all is not lost because it would certainly be possible to write this with a macro at the top level that looks something like the following:

```
(defmacro build-button-protocol [name & method-specs]
    ....)
```

Which you could use as follows:

```
(build-button-protocol view-methods
  (add-methods ok)
  (add-methods cancel)
  (add-methods other))
```

Comment: I thought of that, but I also need to add additional methods to the protocol.